# Conversion of timestamp(long value) to date only(YYYY-MM-DD) in DBT

Tags: date, unix-timestamp, dbt

I'm trying to convert timestamp (long value) into date only (YYYY-MM-DD) with the below query.

```
SELECT
    id,
    scheme_name,
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME({{'scheme_t'}})) AS scheme_date
FROM
    scheme_table;
```

scheme_table definition:- CREATE TABLE scheme_table(
id varchar(225),
scheme_name varchar(225),
scheme_t long
);

input:- 1672492800 (timestamp)
output:- 1970-01-01

Comment: What DBMS are you using?